# Open from notification gives NullException

Tags: android, android-intent, push-notification, android-pendingintent

I'm trying to open my app from a notification push. But I have a problem, I have 3 activities, the activity which works as launcher, and 2 others.

When I click on a push if I do:

`new Intent(this, ClientActivity.class)` the app opens in the activity that was working previously. Is the same if the app was in foreground or background.

The problem is when I click on a notification and the app is killed, the `ClientActivity` is not loaded, so the app produces a `Runtime Exception` because `ClientActivity` was there.

How I can know what Activity is running currently?

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, activityToOpen);
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
if(pushTypeSecureSignature){
    intent.putExtra("PUSH_TYPE_SECURE_SIGNATURE", true);
}
pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 /* Request code */, intent, 0);
```

Comment: Can you post your logs?

Comment: Post the exception with stacktrace from logcat into your question. It isn't clear what your problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a click on the `Notification` to just bring your app to the foreground in whatever state it was in when it went to the background, then just use this:

```
Intent = PackageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage("my.app.package.name")
```

Now wrap this `Intent` in a `PendingIntent` and put it in your `Notification`.

This will bring your app to the foreground (if it is running) in whatever state it was in. If your app is not running, this will just launch the root `Activity` of your app (the same thing that happens when the user taps the app icon on the HOME screen).